# Highcharts 5: TypeError: Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined at e.Chart.reflow

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I recently upgraded from

```
"highcharts-ng": "~0.0.11",
"highcharts-release": "~4.1.9",
"angular-bootstrap": "~0.14.3",
```

to

```
"highcharts-ng": "~1.1.0",
"highcharts-release": "~5.0.11",
"angular-bootstrap": "~0.14.3",
```

and only since then get this problem: I have a single page angular application (Angular 1.5.8) using Bootstrap UI (not sure if that matters). The problem does not exist with highcharts 4 and highcharts-ng 0.0.11.

When I have a page with a **highchart directive** `<highchart class="highchart-hover"  config="chart"></highchart>` in it and I **leave this page by navigating to another page/ route**, I see this error in the Chrome developer console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined
    at e.Chart.reflow (script.js:40411)
    at script.js:40661
    at script.js:25025
    at i (script.js:11128)
    at script.js:11407
    at nrWrapper ((index):43)
```

Following the stack trace, I see the sources as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As mentioned, with the older highcharts/highcharts-ng version, this problem did not exist. 
Any idea what might cause this? I guess there is a check missing whether the chart object actually still exists.

Thanks.

(Unfortunately I don't have a jsfiddle at hand right now for this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with the highcharts-ng library and I filed an issue report here: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/594

Also see the comments there for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the options and data from ngAfterViewInit to the component's constructor.

From

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   data...
   options...
}
```

To

```
constructor(){
   data...
   options...
}
```